# unable to pass table td value to JS function variable

Tags: javascript

I'm trying pass a table td value of HTML to JS variable but the value is not passing from html to js function.

***HTML -***

```
<table id="persontable" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>person name</th>
            <th>address</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="person_table">
        <% @my_persons.all.each do |person| %>
        <tr>
            <td id="selectedPerson" style="word-break:break-all;">
                <%=person.name%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <b id="person_address" style="float: right;">Not available </b>
                <!--&nbsp;&nbsp;<b id="confirm_person"></b>-->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

***JS -***

```
function getSelectedPerson() {
    var person_name = document.getElementById("selectedPerson").value;
    alert(person_name)
}
```

I'm getting a null value.

Comment: Use `document.getElementById("selectedPerson").textContent` instead of `document.getElementById("selectedPerson").value`. `td` is a container, containers don't have a `value` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all elements support `value` property. See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_value.asp) for element supporting `value` property.

For `td`, you can use `innerText` as `document.getElementById("selectedPerson").innerText`

Comment: Thanks.Before i was using select  // person_name = $('#selectedPerson').val(); person_name.length is showing 2 if selected 2 values.Now i have changed to check box.if i am using person_name= document.getElementById("selectedPerson").innerText,person_name.length is not working.It is taking lenth of the content.I want to count of the person which i am selecting in checkboxes.