# Get selected check boxes values from table using Java script

Tags: javascript

I was using select  `Person_name = $('#selectedPerson').val()`

`person_name.length` is showing 2 if selected 2 values.

Now i have changed to check boxes which is in table. If i am using `person_name= document.getElementById("selectedPerson").innerText, person_name.length` is not working. It is taking length of the content. I want to count of the person and it is value which i am selecting in check-boxes.

Thanks,
Raja.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more code, including the relevant HTML?

Comment: Use `.value` instead of `.innerText`

Comment: Getting null.value if I am using Val.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54090937/unable-to-pass-table-td-value-to-js-function-variable/54091422#54091422

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Side note: an ID should only ever be applied to one element, so you want `.selectedPerson` not `#selectedPerson` if it's going to select two things.

```
var people = $('.selectedPerson');
var count = people.count;
var name = people.text();
```

Comment: It'll "work" for certain definitions of "work". It's not clear what exactly you want it to do, but in general separating two different variables for your two different purposes is what you want.

Comment: I have multiple check boxes in table which has person names and I need to select required names and pass the same in Ajax call.